# event.target.value - how to get the key value?

Tags: javascript

There was a need to add a drop-down list with a choice of accounts. The chosen value is processed through "event.target.value". This handler takes the value visible to the user, but I only need the 'key' value of the selected record where the stored "account.Id". I've tried get access to key, but it doesn't seem to work.

First experience with JS, so apologize in advance if the question is incorrect or elementary.

Page:

```
 <select class="slds-select" name = "accountSelect" onchange={changeHandler2} >
    <template for:each={allAccounts.data} for:item="account">
      <option key={account.Id} value={account.Id}>{account.Name}</option>    
    </template>
 </select>
```

Handler:

```
changeHandler(event) {
  if (field === 'accountSelect') {
  this.accountId = event.target.options[event.target.selectedIndex].getAttribute('key');
  }
}
```

Comment: What framework are you using? I almost thought it was React, but as far as I know, React has nothing like the `for:each` / `for:item` syntax you're using.

Comment: why bother with the "key" attribute when the standard "value" attribute appears to contain identical data (both contain accountID). So you could just get the "value" of the select (since the value of the currently selected option is always used as the value of the overall select) and get your info that way.

Comment: @IceMetalPunk It's a LWC - Lightning Web Component for Salesforce.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you tried to use the data to get it :

```
changeHandler(event) {
  if (field === 'accountSelect') {
   this.accountId = allAccounts.data.find(item => item.Id === event.target.value);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Direct access to value did not help, but your method worked.